# ZXingScannerView scan bulk mode in handleresult

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to implement Bulk Scan mode in me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9 library. This is my snippet codes. Im trying to do multiple scan which from the codes for now i just trying to display each of the scan result in messagedialogue. however, after the first scan resulthandler, the second time scan automatically kill the activity.

```
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
private boolean mFlash;
private boolean mAutoFocus;
private int mCameraId = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
setupFormats();
contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);
}

//i want to make my scanner able to keep scanning getting the result.
//however after the first scan, the second scan will automatically close the activity
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
try {
   if(!result.getText().equals("")){
    //In message dialogue will have 1 button handle on onDialogPositiveClick 
            showMessageDialog("Contents = " + result.getText() + ", Format = 
            " + result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
   }
 } catch (Exception e) {

 } finally {

 }
}

public void showMessageDialog(String message) {
    DialogFragment fragment = MessageDialogFragment.newInstance("Scan 
     Results", message, this);
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "scan_results");
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
    closeMessageDialog();
    closeFormatsDialog();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera(mCameraId);
    mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with onActivityResult

```
/*Here is where we come back after the Barcode Scanner is done*/
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{ 
 if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // contents contains whatever the code was
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "PRODUCT_MODE,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // start the next scan
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        //do whatever else you want.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add handler or TimerTask for secondTime Scan.after get first scan result in handleResult you have to start scanning again after some delay, whatever delay you want add to handler.

```
@Override
    public void handleResult(final Result rawResult) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleDecode(rawResult);
            }
        });
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(CaptureActivity.this);
            }
        }, 4000);// 4 sec delay to restart scan again.
    }
```